# Creating a random permutation of 1..N with Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable

Tags: haskell, vector

I want to create a list containing a random permutation of the numbers 1 through N. As I understand it, it is possible to use `VUM.swap` in the runST, but since I need random numbers as well I figured I might do both in the IO monad.

The code below yields:

> Expected type: IO (VU.Vector Int), Actual type: IO (VU.Vector
>   (VU.Vector a0))

for the return statement.

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed         as VU
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VUM
import           System.Random

randVector :: Int -> IO (VU.Vector Int)
randVector n = do
  vector <- VU.unsafeThaw $ VU.enumFromN 1 n
  VU.forM_ (VU.fromList [2..VUM.length vector]) $ \i -> do
    j <- randomRIO(0, i) :: IO Int
    VUM.swap vector i j
  return $ VU.unsafeFreeze vector
```

I'm not quite sure why the return vector is nested. Do I have to use `VU.fold1M_` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unsafeFreeze vector` already returns `IO (VU.Vector Int)`. Just change the last line to `VU.unsafeFreeze vector`.

On another note, you should iterate until `VUM.length vector - 1`, since both `[x .. y]` and `randomRIO` use inclusive ranges. Also, you can use plain `forM_` here for iteration, since you only care about side effects.

```
import           Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed         as VU
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VUM
import           System.Random

randVector :: Int -> IO (VU.Vector Int)
randVector n = do
  vector <- VU.unsafeThaw $ VU.enumFromN 1 n
  forM_ [2..VUM.length vector - 1] $ \i -> do
    j <- randomRIO(0, i) :: IO Int
    VUM.swap vector i j
  VU.unsafeFreeze vector
```

I looked at the generated code, and it seems that with GHC 7.10.3 `forM_` compiles to an efficient loop while `VU.forM_` retains the intermediate list and is surely significantly slower (which was my expected outcome for `forM_`, but I was unsure about `VU.forM_`).

Comment: That did the trick! The return statement was the problem. How come using return nested the vector? I would never have figured that out. I used `VU.forM_` instead of the plain version because I was unsure where the plain version was to be found. Typical input size is n=50 and building 5000 randVectors, I can't imagine the different for-loops will be many seconds different.

Comment: I added a comment on the `forM_` bounds and edited the bit on `forM_` performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would try (note update at end):

```
import Control.Monad

randVector :: Int -> IO (VU.Vector Int)
randVector n = do
  vector <- VU.unsafeThaw $ VU.enumFromN 1 n
  forM_ [2..VUM.length vector] $ \i -> do
    j <- randomRIO(0, i) :: IO Int
    VUM.swap vector i j
  return $ VU.unsafeFreeze vector
```

Edit: as @András Kovács pointed out, you don't want the `return` at the end so the last line should be:

```
  VU.unsafeFreeze vector
```